# other ways to pull values from a nodelist of html elements

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

So, I'm creating an e-commerce page and I have an event when the purchase button is clicked to pull all the names (and quantities) of the items. I'm doing this to eventually check their inventory availability in the DB but this is irrelevant for my question.

I've finally figured out how to get those said item names into an Array. However, the code I found to work seems strange at first glanced. I was wondering if anyone could think of other ways of doing this just for the sake of my curiosity and maybe something that's more sensible to look at for a somewhat amateur programmer like myself

I suppose I should say specifically the [].map.call( section is what looks strange to me... So you're creating an empty array and calling map which is applying a function to every element of the array. then the .call (which is the part where the confusion is sort of coming up) is used to assign a this keyword to the first parameter and the 2nd parameter is the function to grab the value. so is call simply used to assign this to be able to iterate over the nodelist?

here is a mock up html of the cart:

```
<div class="cart-row">
                <div class="cart-item cart-column">
                    <img class="cart-item-image" src="Images/Shirt.png" width="100" height="100">
                    <span class="cart-item-title">T-Shirt</span>
                </div>
                <span class="cart-price cart-column">$19.99</span>
                <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                    <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <div class="cart-item cart-column">
                    <img class="cart-item-image" src="Images/coffee_cup.png" width="100" height="100">
                    <span class="cart-item-title">Coffee Cup</span>
                </div>
                <span class="cart-price cart-column">$9.99</span>
                <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                    <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="2">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and here is the JS I used to pull the item titles from the nodelist:

```
const titlesArray = [].map.call(
  cartItemsContainer.querySelectorAll(".cart-item-title"),
  function (el) {
    return el.innerText;
  }
```

Comment: The general approach is fine, but you can modernize `[].map.call()`, either using `Array.from(cartItemsContainer.querySelectorAll(".cart-item-title")).map()` or `[...cartItemsContainer.querySelectorAll(".cart-item-title")].map()`.

Comment: okay the second half of this was the route i tried to approach the problem with first. I thought I did something similar to this but instead of .map I used forEach and it was giving me undefined issues. but now i'm realizing that i can't use .forEach because it doesn't return values. wow...thank you so much. of course a silly mistake to waste a morning lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, nodelist is not an array and just a collection of nodes. So, you cant call array methods on a nodelist but as @Barmar said you can convert a nodelist to array. By this means you are capable to use array methods.
When you look at [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), you can see that "forEach" method works on nodelist.
As an example to reach dom elements and write them to an array:

```js
const yourArray = []
document.querySelectorAll('.cart-item-title').forEach((elem, index) =>  {
console.log('Title ' + (index + 1) + ': ' ,elem)
yourArray.push(elem.textContent)
})
console.log('with forEach method : ', yourArray)

const myArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cart-item-title')).map(elem => elem.textContent)
console.log('with map method : ', myArray)
```

```html
<div class="cart-row">
    <div class="cart-item cart-column">
        <img class="cart-item-image" src="Images/Shirt.png" width="100" height="100">
        <span class="cart-item-title">T-Shirt</span>
    </div>
    <span class="cart-price cart-column">$19.99</span>
    <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
        <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cart-row">
    <div class="cart-item cart-column">
        <img class="cart-item-image" src="Images/coffee_cup.png" width="100" height="100">
        <span class="cart-item-title">Coffee Cup</span>
    </div>
    <span class="cart-price cart-column">$9.99</span>
    <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
        <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="2">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is using `[].map.call(nodeList, transformFunction)` to circumvent missing array methods.

Comment: he/she is also asking usage with forEach on the comments

Comment: ahhh! interesting. Thanks for using the .forEach. I just failed to remember that forEach doesn't return anything into an array which is what I was trying to do. I could've simply pushed each el into an already existing empty array. 

Thanks for the examples. I was so close but so far xD